# Transparent Images

Tags: html, png, jpeg, transparent, gif

Does anyone know if IE now supports transparent png's etc...? Does chrome as well?

Comment: Which version of IE? 7? 8? 9?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IE7+, and every other modern browser including Chrome, supports PNGs with alpha channels.

The only drawback to watch out for in IE7-8 is that alpha channels do not play nicely with the IE-specific `alpha` filter typically used as fallback for CSS `opacity`.

Answer (score 2):

Every mayor browser does (so that includes chrome). Only IE6 doesn't, but I wouldn't consider that a problem. So yes, you can use semi-transparent png's.

Comment: There are also several javascript-based fixes for IE6. So, as long as you don't mind another file, you can use transparent and semi-transparent PNG's in IE6 as well.

Answer (score 0):

The older versions of IE don't support transparency, but there are a lot of fixes out there -- for example, http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/.